# Orchard Taxonomies Shape Alternates by displayType

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I am using the shape tracer in order to use an alternate view of one of my taxonomie fields called location. However unlike other shapes the alternates do not give the option for different display types in this case summary or details. So by changing 1 you change the other. I need to be able to do them independently.

I have a  view created see below **Fields.Contrib.TaxonomyField-Location.cshtml** but as i say this is rendered the same if the display type is details or summary.

How to i overcome this please.

Thanks Jon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I had the same problem not long ago](http://kobowi.co.uk/blog/2012/11/content-display-type-alternates-for-content-parts-in-orchard/). You can provide your own alternates by implementing a `ShapeDisplayEvents` class.

Here is an implementation that gives you alternates based on the content type, display type, or both:

```
public class PartContentTypeAlternateFactory : ShapeDisplayEvents {
    public override void Displaying(ShapeDisplayingContext context) {
        context.ShapeMetadata.OnDisplaying(displayedContext => {
            var shapeType = displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Type;
            var contentItem = displayedContext.Shape.ContentItem;
            var displayType = displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.DisplayType;
            var contentType = contentItem.ContentType;
            displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add(
                String.Format("{0}__{1}", shapeType, displayType));
            displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add(
                String.Format("{0}__{1}__{2}", shapeType, (string)contentType, displayType));
            });
    }
}
```

You will end up with some extra alternates appearing in the shape tracer, like this:

[image]

And you can now use an alternate named `Fields.Contrib.TaxonomyField-Location-Summary` or `Fields.Contrib.TaxonomyField-Location-Detail` etc. You can extend this class to add whatever alternates you want.

**Edit**

I didn't realise you couldn't easily get to the field name, so try something like this - it does something similar to what the `UrlAlternatesFactory` does, i.e. it loops over the existing alternates and adds the displayType to them. This should give you an alternate that contains both the field name and the display type.

```
public class PartContentTypeAlternateFactory : ShapeDisplayEvents {
    public override void Displaying(ShapeDisplayingContext context) {
        context.ShapeMetadata.OnDisplaying(displayedContext => {
            var alternates = displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Select(a => a + "__" + displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.DisplayType);
            displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Alternates = displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Union(alternates).ToList();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help looks like just the thing. i will give that a go!

Comment: Sorry but where do you put the cs file.

Comment: Ah, sorry i should have said - it needs to go in a module as it won't work if you add it to a theme. Can point you in the general direction to get started if you don't have one you can use.

Comment: Actually it should work in a theme, provided the theme has a csproj file.

Comment: Thanks both, i have the shape tracer working now showing summary. However i cant get to the write level. I have taxonomies of House with 2 sub levels 1 location and 1 property type. Now i am trying to get ields.Contrib.TaxonomyField-Location-Summary but i can get ields.Contrib.TaxonomyField-House-Summary or ields.Contrib.TaxonomyField-Location. 
See image of shape tracer after selecting the taxonomy House > Location: http://www.screencast.com/t/duZuJUWxZt6

(dont know how to imbed the image sorry)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks again for the help. Still does not work for me though using the new override instead of the first BUT If i append your edit to the first function it works, but i feel is overkill as you can get the display type twice. So i am trying a few tweaks to merge the code checking if the shape has the display type at the end already. Any suggestions be great.

Comment: I just noticed a problem with the second edit - where it references `context` it should be `displayedContext` instead. Have updated.

Comment: you are a genious, thanks for your help. i managed to get it working after merging the 2 overrides u provided and using a regex on a where  (var alternates = displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Where(a => Regex.Matches(a, displayType).Count == 0).Select(a => a + "__" + displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.DisplayType);). BUT then after your edit above i didnt need to merge, so now just using your edit from above. THANKS FOR YOU HELP!! Really appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, sorry for the duff code second time around. Glad you got it working :)